# CSS, two flexible fields of variable width, each takes up 50% if long

Tags: css, html, layout

I have several rows of email address and name.  I would like to show as much content as I can.  So, if I have a short name, show more email address, and if I have a short email, show more name.  If both name and email are long, I'd like them to take an equal amount of space.  And for any long, truncated item, I'd like them to end with an ellipsis.

Is there anyways I can keep these requirements without resorting to Javascript?   I'd prefer not to use flexbox layouts (not enough browser support), but I'd be open to it. Also, everything is a single line; no wrapping.

```
------------- -------------------------------------
| This is a long name...| This is a long email... |
------------- -------------------------------------

|<------------------100% width ------------------>|


<div class='result'>
  <div class='textHolder'>
   <h3>Name</h3>
   <h4>Email</h4>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: H3 and h4 elements seem semantically inappropriate here.  Headlines are supposed to be for headlining sections of content.  Maybe a table or definition list would be more appropriate?

Comment: This is a good point, @cimmanon, thank you.  I overlooked this.

Comment: Not seeing a good pure CSS solution here with the ellipsis requirement (table http://cssdeck.com/labs/gkelmysp vs flexbox http://cssdeck.com/labs/izktkdre).

Comment: Added the additional requirement of being a single line.

Answer (score 1):

@Newtang I've updated the JSFiddle to your requirements. When you expand and contract the page, if the page width is too small the ellipses will appear.

Here's the link http://jsfiddle.net/6gFN9/1/

```
.textHolder {
    width: 100%;
}
h3, h4 {
    float: left;
    max-width: 50%;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Without javascript, the only solution that I think would work is giving a `max-width` of 50% to each, and a `text-overflow` with an ellipsis (…) when the text overflows...

The only problem is if for instance the name is very small, if the email is very big it will ocupy only 50% of the full width.

I made this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/N36tY/

(also I agree with cimmanon, use other tags)

Example HTML:

```
<div class='result'>
    <div class='textHolder'>
         <h3>Name</h3>

         <h4>Email</h4>

        <div class="clear"></div>
         <h3>Name and more text, etc and even more to make it overflow</h3>

         <h4>Email</h4>

        <div class="clear"></div>
         <h3>Name and more text, etc and even more to make it overflow</h3>

         <h4>Email and a lot of text and more and even more to make it overflow</h4>

        <div class="clear"></div>
         <h3>Small name</h3>

         <h4>Email and a lot of text and more and even more to make it overflow</h4>

    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.textHolder {
    width: 100%;
}
h3 {
    background: blue;
    color: #FFF;
}
h4 {
    background: green;
    color: #FFF;
}
h3, h4 {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: normal;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    min-width: 10px;
    max-width: 50%;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.clear {
    clear: both;
}
```